# insta.pyのpythonコードでのエラー処理の仕方がわからない

Tags: python, instagram

コードを書いたのですが以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました、どうすれば直りますかね。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
INFO [2022-05-04 15:12:28] [whowho_netshop]  Session started!
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
INFO [2022-05-04 15:12:28] [whowho_netshop]  -- Connection Checklist [1/2] (Internet Connection Status)
WARNING [2022-05-04 15:12:29] [whowho_netshop]  - Internet Connection Status: error
............................................................................................................................
CRITICAL [2022-05-04 15:12:29] [whowho_netshop]  Unable to login to Instagram! You will find more information in the logs above.
```

**現状のコード:**

```
""" Quickstart script for InstaPy usage """

# imports
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run
from instapy import set_workspace

# login credentials
#自分のアカウント名と、自分のパスワードを打ち込みます
insta_username = 'アカウント名を入力'
insta_password = 'パスワードを入力'


# set workspace folder at desired location (default is at your home folder)
set_workspace(path=None)

# get an InstaPy session!
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                  password=insta_password,
                  headless_browser=True)

with smart_run(session):
    # general settings
    # Excluding friends 
    # will prevent commenting on and unfollowing your good friends (the images will still be liked)
    session.set_dont_include(["friend1", "friend2", "friend3"])

    # 実行（以下にイイネしたいタグ名を入力します、●●にはイイネする回数を入力します）
    session.like_by_tags(["タグ名を入力"], amount=●●)
       #tags: The tags that will be searched for and posts will be liked from
       #amount: The amount of posts that will be liked

       #実行にあたっては以下のURLを参照
       #https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#like-by-tags
```

Comment: 実行しているコードは次のページのものでしょうか？ https://mame-mame.hatenadiary.com/entry/2020/04/26/154741

Comment: あ、それですそれです！！！

Comment: `insta_username` や  "タグ名を入力" や `amount=●●` の部分は実際の(該当する)値に変更してるのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そこは全て入力した状態ですね